# Receive original path of HttpRequest if error occurs

Tags: spring, servlets, httprequest, httpresponse, interceptor

I'm writing simple interceptor that will collect data from all requests and responses I'm receiving and sending and streams it to external queue, where I can filter that and see that I had:
100 calls at /test, 95 ended with status 200, 4 ended with status 400, 1 ended with status 500

I wrote class that looks like this

```
@Component
public class HttpEventInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    private final HttpEventStream eventStream;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public HttpEventInterceptor(HttpEventStream eventStream) {
        this.eventStream = eventStream;
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        final var eventJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(createHttpEvent(request, response));
        eventStream.outboundEvents().send(MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(eventJson)
                .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .build());
    }

    private HttpEvent createHttpEvent(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        final var event = new HttpEvent();
        event.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        event.setMethod(request.getMethod());
        event.setUrl(request.getRequestURI()); // <-- This isn't working as expected
        event.setResponseCode(response.getStatus());
        return event;
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work fine, except one thing. 
Let's say, I call endpoint /test with bad request and I receive HttpStatus 400 Bad Request as expected. But, at this point `request.getRequestURI()` called in `createHttpEvent()` isn't returning /test but /error. How do I reach original called endpoint at this point?

I'v tried to `@Override` `preHandle()` too, but it is the same, also I need to combine data from both request and response so I'd prefer to do this in `postHandle()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How do I reach original called endpoint at this point?*

As per Servlet API spec 10.9.1, the default error handler saves it as a request attribute with the name identified by [`RequestDispatcher#ERROR_REQUEST_URI`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#ERROR_REQUEST_URI).

So, it must be available as follows:

```
String originalRequestURI = (String) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_REQUEST_URI);
// ...
```